# Dlib and face-recognition file Installation issue in face-recognition project

Tags: python, opencv, pycharm, conv-neural-network, face-recognition

I am trying to run the face-recognition project in pycham. There was no requirement file in that project. To create that file I take help from google collab and generate the requirement.txt file.

then I paste the requirement.txt file into the folder and run the project in pycham IDE.
Create a new environment and run this command pip install -r requirements.txt
All necessary libraries install except Dlib and face-recognition give an error [picture-error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2YyX.png)

A screenshot of the error is attached. any solution or alternative to this issue?

Comment: The error states that it found "no mathcing distribution" from "numnpy". Is it not a typo? Isn't it meant to be "numpy"?

Comment: no, it is not numpy error. NumPy already installed I am facing an issue when I install dlib library cmake library in installed already. then I need to install dlib then face recognition. it gives an error while installing dlip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with a dependecy you have called `dlip` .
For some reason it is in your requirements.txt , which I think is just an error.

Anyway, I poked around the METADATA file of the [dlip-0.0.1 wheel](https://pypi.org/project/dlip/) and saw that it wrongly tries to install `numnpy` as dependency (instead of `numpy`) . See:

[image]

So I guess what you want to do is remove the `dlip` dependecy from the `requirements.txt`. it seems to me that you have a typo there, and it just should have been `dlib`.